# Calling method from one class in other

Tags: java

I know that this kind of issue has been discussed here many times, but I'm confused. I'm totally beginner in Java and I honestly don't know what to do and I admit that I don't have that much time to read whole documentation provided by Oracle. Here's my problem:

I'm trying to program a GUI for my program that will be show interference of acoustic waves. Mathematical functionality doesn't matter in here. I've got two classes called Window and Sliders. Window is intended to be a 'main GUI class' and Sliders is supposed to inherit (?) from it.

This comes from another issue that I need to implement ActionListener in class Window and ChangeListener in Sliders class. I heard that one class can't implement several classes that's why I made two.

Now, I wrote a little bit chaotic those two classes, but I don't know how to combine them. It's really silly, but after C++ I'm pretty confused how to tell the program that it is supposed to show in one frame either buttons defined in Window class and sliders defined in Sliders class. Currently it shows only buttons I want to make it showing sliders too.

I'm very sorry for chaotic pseudo code, please help. Please, try to explain as simply as you can/possible. Please feel free to ignore overrided methods, they're not finished yet.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;

public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

private JButton showChord, playSound, getSample, getPlot;
private JLabel chordInfo;
private JPanel basicFunctions;

public Window()
{
    init();
}

private void init()
{
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(new Dimension(1000,500));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    basicFunctions = new JPanel();
    FlowLayout basicLayout = new FlowLayout();
    basicFunctions.setLayout(basicLayout);

    showChord = new JButton("Akord");
    playSound = new JButton("Odtwórz");
    getSample = new JButton("Pobierz dźwięk");
    getPlot = new JButton("Pobierz wykres");

    showChord.addActionListener(this);
    playSound.addActionListener(this);
    getSample.addActionListener(this);
    getPlot.addActionListener(this);

    basicFunctions.add(showChord);
    basicFunctions.add(playSound);
    basicFunctions.add(getSample);
    basicFunctions.add(getPlot);
    add(basicFunctions);

    Sliders param = new Sliders();

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Window frame = new Window();
}

//Action Listener
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) 
{
    Object event = a.getSource();

    if(event == showChord)
    {

    }

    else if(event == playSound)
    {

    }

    else if(event == getSample)
    {

    }

    else if(event == getPlot)
    {

    }
}


}

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


public class Sliders extends Window implements ChangeListener
{
private JPanel sliders, sliderSub;
private JTextField accAmplitude, accFrequency, accPhase;
private JSlider amplitude, frequency, phase;
private double amplitudeValue, frequencyValue, phaseValue;

public Sliders()
{
    sliders = new JPanel();
    sliders.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    amplitude = new JSlider(0,100,0);

    amplitude.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
    amplitude.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
    amplitude.setPaintTicks(true);
    amplitude.setPaintLabels(true);

    frequency = new JSlider(0,10,0);

    frequency.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
    frequency.setMinorTickSpacing(1/10);
    frequency.setPaintTicks(true);
    frequency.setPaintLabels(true);

    phase = new JSlider(0,1,0);

    phase.setMinorTickSpacing(2/10);
    phase.setPaintTicks(true);
    phase.setPaintLabels(true);

    accAmplitude = new JTextField();
    accFrequency = new JTextField();
    accPhase = new JTextField();

    sliders.add(amplitude, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    sliders.add(frequency, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    sliders.add(phase, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(sliders);
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) 
{


}
}
```

---

I've done this so far, but those text fields just stopped showing sliders values and I don't know why. They are defined in the Parameters class and Window class. Can someone help? Additionally in the future I'd like to make those text fields editable so that you can set slider value by typing it in the text field.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Window extends JPanel
{
private JMenuBar mainMenu = new JMenuBar();

private Plot plot = new Plot();
private Parameters param = new Parameters();

private JComboBox chooseChord = new JComboBox();

private JButton playSound = new JButton("Odtwórz");
private JButton getSample = new JButton("Pobierz dźwięk");
private JButton getPlot = new JButton("Pobierz wykres");

private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel slidersPanel = new JPanel();

private JLabel chord = new JLabel("Akord:");

private JTextField aValue = new JTextField();
private JTextField fValue = new JTextField(); 
private JTextField pValue = new JTextField();

public Window() 
{
    mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    buttonsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonsPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    slidersPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    subPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    chooseChord.addItem("A");
    chooseChord.addItem("A#");
    chooseChord.addItem("Ab");
    chooseChord.addItem("B");
    chooseChord.addItem("Bb");
    chooseChord.addItem("C");
    chooseChord.addItem("C#");
    chooseChord.addItem("Cb");
    chooseChord.addItem("D");
    chooseChord.addItem("D#");
    chooseChord.addItem("E");
    chooseChord.addItem("F");
    chooseChord.addItem("F#");

    buttonsPanel.add(chord);
    buttonsPanel.add(chooseChord);
    buttonsPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
    buttonsPanel.add(playSound);
    buttonsPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
    buttonsPanel.add(getSample);
    buttonsPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
    buttonsPanel.add(getPlot);
    buttonsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Menu"));

    slidersPanel.add(param);

    JMenu langMenu = new JMenu("Język");
    mainMenu.add(langMenu);

    subPanel.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    subPanel.add(slidersPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    mainPanel.add(subPanel);
    mainPanel.add(plot);
    add(mainPanel);

    param.addAmplitudeListener(new ChangeListener()
    {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent a)
        {
            double ampValue = param.getAmplitudeValue();
            aValue.setText(String.valueOf(ampValue));
        }
    }
    );


    param.addFrequencyListener(new ChangeListener()
    {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent f)
        {
            double frValue = param.getFrequencyValue();
            fValue.setText(String.valueOf(frValue));
        }
    }
    );


    param.addPhaseListener(new ChangeListener()
    {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent p)
        {
            double phValue = param.getPhaseValue();
            pValue.setText(String.valueOf(phValue));
        }
    }
    );


}

public JMenuBar getmainMenu()
{
    return mainMenu;
}

private static void GUI()
{
    Window mainPanel = new Window();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    frame.setJMenuBar(mainPanel.getmainMenu());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
         public void run()
         {
            GUI();
         }
      }
      );
}
}

class Parameters extends JPanel
{
    private JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    private JPanel ampPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel frPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel phPanel = new JPanel();

    private JSlider amplitude = new JSlider(0,100,0);
    private JSlider frequency = new JSlider(0,10000,0);
    private JSlider phase = new JSlider(0,180,0);

    private JLabel pLabel = new JLabel("Faza");
    private JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("Amplituda (dB)");
    private JLabel fLabel = new JLabel("Częstotliwość (Hz)");

    private JTextField preciseAmplitude = new JTextField(3);
    private JTextField preciseFrequency = new JTextField(4); 
    private JTextField precisePhase = new JTextField(3);

    public Parameters()
    {
        preciseAmplitude.setEditable(true);
        preciseFrequency.setEditable(true);
        precisePhase.setEditable(true);

        pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        ampPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        phPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        amplitude.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        amplitude.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
        amplitude.setPaintTicks(true);
        amplitude.setPaintLabels(true);

        frequency.setMajorTickSpacing(2000);
        frequency.setMinorTickSpacing(100);
        frequency.setPaintTicks(true);
        frequency.setPaintLabels(true);

        phase.setMajorTickSpacing(2/10);
        phase.setPaintTicks(true);
        phase.setPaintLabels(true);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Parametry fali"));

        ampPanel.add(aLabel);
        ampPanel.add(preciseAmplitude);
        pane.add(ampPanel);
        pane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,5)));
        pane.add(amplitude);
        pane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));

        frPanel.add(fLabel);
        frPanel.add(preciseFrequency);
        pane.add(frPanel);
        pane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,5)));
        pane.add(frequency);
        pane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));

        phPanel.add(pLabel);
        phPanel.add(precisePhase);
        pane.add(phPanel);
        pane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,5)));
        pane.add(phase);
        pane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));

        add(pane);

    }

    public int getAmplitudeValue()
    {
        return amplitude.getValue();
    }

    public int getFrequencyValue()
    {
        return frequency.getValue();
    }

    public int getPhaseValue()
    {
        return phase.getValue();
    }

    public void addAmplitudeListener(ChangeListener ampListener) 
    {
          amplitude.addChangeListener(ampListener);
    }

    public void addFrequencyListener(ChangeListener frListener) 
    {
          frequency.addChangeListener(frListener);
    }

    public void addPhaseListener(ChangeListener phListener) 
    {
          phase.addChangeListener(phListener);
    }
}

class Plot extends JPanel
{
private JPanel componentWave = new JPanel();
private JPanel netWave = new JPanel();
private JLabel componentLabel = new JLabel("Fale składowe");
private JLabel netLabel = new JLabel("Fala wypadkowa");
private JLabel wave = new JLabel("Wybierz falę składową");
private JPanel labels = new JPanel();
private JComboBox chooseWave = new JComboBox();

public Plot()
{
    labels.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labels, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    componentWave.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
    netWave.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
    componentWave.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
    netWave.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));

    componentWave.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,200));
    netWave.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,200));

    labels.add(wave);
    labels.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
    labels.add(chooseWave);
    labels.add(componentLabel);
    labels.add(componentWave);
    labels.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,20)));
    labels.add(netLabel);
    labels.add(netWave);

    add(labels);
}
}
```

Comment: ActionListener and ChangeListener are interfaces, not classes, and thus you can implement (not inherit) any number of them.

Comment: **But** as a general rule, your view class, the GUIs, should not implement listener interfaces as that's asking the view to do too much since the class would break the "Single Responsibility Rule"

Comment: How can I implement more than one interface? That would be fine with me, but the problem is something else. Writing one-class programs all the time doesn't make sense, I need to learn how to combine many classes in Java. I assume that "Single Responsibility Rule" is quite important, but I don't have an idea how to write my first program that would fulfill whis requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Window is intended to be a 'main GUI class' and Sliders is supposed to inherit (?) from it.

Nope: this is a misuse of inheritance and will only lead to problems since the Windows instance that Sliders inherently is, is completely distinct from the displayed Windows instance. What you need to do is to pass references.

For example, the following code uses outside classes for the JButton and JMenuItem Actions (Actions are like ActionListeners on steroids), and uses a class that holds a JSlider that allows itside classes to attach listeners to the slider.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Foo extends JPanel {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private Action helloAction = new HelloAction("Hello", KeyEvent.VK_H);
   private Action exitAction = new ExitAction("Exit", KeyEvent.VK_X);
   private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
   private JTextField sliderValueField = new JTextField(10);
   private Bar bar = new Bar();

   public Foo() {
      sliderValueField.setEditable(false);
      sliderValueField.setFocusable(false);

      add(new JButton(helloAction));
      add(new JButton(exitAction));
      add(new JLabel("Slider Value: "));
      add(sliderValueField);
      add(bar);

      JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
      fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
      fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem(exitAction));
      fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem(helloAction));
      menuBar.add(fileMenu);

      bar.addSliderListener(new ChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            int sliderValue = bar.getSliderValue();
            sliderValueField.setText(String.valueOf(sliderValue));
         }
      });
   }

   public JMenuBar getJMenuBar() {
      return menuBar;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Foo mainPanel = new Foo();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.setJMenuBar(mainPanel.getJMenuBar());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class HelloAction extends AbstractAction {

   public HelloAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
      super(name); // sets name property and gives button its title
      putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello!");
   }
}

class ExitAction extends AbstractAction {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public ExitAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
      super(name);
      putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Component component = (Component) e.getSource();
      Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(component);
      if (win == null) {
         // if no window, then a JMenuItem held in a JPopupMenu
         JPopupMenu popup = (JPopupMenu) component.getParent();
         component = popup.getInvoker();
         win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(component);
      }
      win.dispose();
   }
}

class Bar extends JPanel {
   private JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 100, 50);

   public Bar() {
      slider.setPaintLabels(true);
      slider.setPaintTicks(true);
      slider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
      slider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
      slider.setSnapToTicks(true);
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Slider Panel"));
      add(slider);
   }

   public int getSliderValue() {
      return slider.getValue();
   }

   // one way to let outside classes listen for changes
   public void addSliderListener(ChangeListener listener) {
      slider.addChangeListener(listener);
   }
}
```

---

You ask about decimal labels, and yes this can be done but requires use of a label table. For example,

```
  JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 100, 50);
  slider.setPaintLabels(true);
  slider.setPaintTicks(true);
  slider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
  slider.setMinorTickSpacing(2);

  Dictionary<Integer, JLabel> labels = new Hashtable<>();
  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 20) {
     labels.put(i, new JLabel(String.format("%.1f", i / 200.0)));
  }

  slider.setLabelTable(labels);
```

Which displays as:

[image]

You would also have to translate the value back from int to its corresponding floating point number.

Comment: One more question: is there any possible way to make minor ticks in slider that are decimal value? I mean 0.1, 0.2, etc.

Comment: @Colonder: yes, but then you'd have to set the JSlider's labelTable via the `setLabelTable(...)` method.

Comment: @Colonder: you have a new problem it seems. It may be related to the original problem but still it's a new problem. Consider accepting this answer and asking a new question on this site.